# How to extract n character from string in BOURNE SHELL?

Tags: linux, shell, substring

I want to extract a substring with n characters from a string in **bourne shell**.
Here is my example:

```
#!/bin/sh
MAC=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

Result: 

MAC_SUBSTR=XX:XX:XX:X
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution in bourne shell not in bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cut` to cut parts of sting.

```
mac_substr=$(printf "%s\n" "$mac" | cut -b 1-9)
```

Prefer to use lower case variables in scripts. Check your scripts with shellcheck.

---

It's very, very unlikely that you are using "Bourne Shell". It is not anywhere used anymore. The common close implementations of POSIX sh are `dash` (I think used in ubuntu now) and Busybox `ash` (alpine linux), where `ash` supports variable expansion to extract a substring:

```
mac_substr=${mac:1:9}
```

`dash` does not support it.

Comment: I am using dash. As you already said dash does not support this syntax: mac_substr=${mac:1:9} ... so I was looking for an other solution. Thank you